# bash scripting - echo only if not empty

Tags: bash, echo, newline

Is there an option or something I can use to encapsulate echo statements so that they don't print if the line is empty?

I was thinking something like:

```
myecho(str){
  if [[ -z str ]]; then
    echo str
  fi
}
```

but I couldn't find how to pass parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Arguments to functions are passed like arguments to scripts. Starting at `$1` until `$n`

```
myecho(){
    if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
        echo "$@"
    fi
}

myecho ""
myecho "foo"
```

Using `-n` in a test you can verify that a string is not empty. Learn more about functions in bash: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html

Comment: `myecho() { if [ -n "$1" ] ; then echo "$@" ; fi }` would be more correct, using all arguments to the function.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
[ -n "${STRING}" ] && echo ${STRING}
```

Or the complementer version:

```
[ -z "${STRING}" ] || echo ${STRING}
```

Or you can do some "echo magic":

```
echo -en "Some prependig text before the empty string: \""
echo -n "${STRING}"
echo -e "\" and some postfix text..."
```

Comment: this. Eloquent and a good bash skill/idiom to master,.

Answer (score 1):

```
function echo2() {
   if [ -n "$1" ]
   then
      echo "$1"
   fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (Shell Parameter Expansion), echoes `${str}\n` if `str` is not null or unset:

```
echo -n ${str:+$str\n} # ${str+$str\n} also works
```

Answer (score -4):

This should work:

```
echo. 

or

echo. SOMEVARIABLE_WHICH_WILL_NOT_OUTPUT_IF_EMPTY
```